# Text wrapping in pivot header

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, pivot, word-wrap

I am looking for a correct way to enable text wrapping in the header of Pivot control in my WP8 application.

Here is the code:

```
<phone:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
    <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

    <phone:PivotItem Header="very long item name">
        <Grid/>
    </phone:PivotItem>
</phone:Pivot>
```

As you can see the 'TextWrapping' property is explicitly set to 'Wrap', but I do not observe any wrapping whatsoever. Does anyone know the workaround?

Comment: The TextWrapping property appears to work for TitleTemplate, but does not work for HeaderTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Width of TextBlock explicitly for TextWrapping to work.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="400" Height="Auto"/>
```

Above works fine.

Comment: Yes, I've already found this solution, but it is not ideal as well. My application supports both orientations, so the width won't be the same. What about different screen resolutions?

Comment: Also I use ItemTemplate to generate pivot items dynamically. What am I supposed to do? Alter widths each time when new items added? Handle orientation changed event to change widths of all existing items? Why the hell this simple thing cannot just work out-of-the-box?

Comment: I think MaxWidth=400 would be a better solution. This would take care of the fact that only items which exceed 400 are wrapped. In this case, you would still need to keep two values of MaxWidth (say 400 & 700) for portrait and landscape respectively. I think two values can be managed.